# Сайт сдвигается при появлении ползунка

Tags: javascript, css

У меня на сайте стоит аякс, но когда к странице добавляется скроллбар, то сайт сдвигается, как сделать, чтобы он был всегда на одном месте, когда есть или нету скроллбара.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/79543/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - закрепить вертикальный скролл, чтобы он был всегда:
    html { overflow-y: scroll; }

Comment: нет, это не вариант

Answer (score 1):

Можно так же отключить, если он не нужен.
А вообще, пробуй с абсолютным позиционированием, например: `.element_class{position: absolute}`, но это плохой выход.

У меня, если не получается что то в css, я просто переписываю его и структурирую так, что бы было все предельно понятно.